Show that $\int_0^1 e^{-\frac{1}{x}}dx > \frac{1}{4}e^{-\frac{4}{3}}$
I wanted to prove that some integral is bounded by a number. After some steps I got that I need to show this: $\int_0^1 e^{-\frac{1}{x}}dx > \frac{1}{4}e^{-\frac{4}{3}}$. But I can't find a good function to compare with $e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$ in order to show this inequality.

$\displaystyle\operatorname{E_{i}}\left(-1\right) + {1 \over {\rm e}} \approx 0.1485$

@FelixMarin umm.. I know that from wolframalpha but I need to compare this with integral of another function to get that inequality. Not directly by approximations

$\int_0^1 e^{-\frac{1}{x}}dx > \int_{3/4}^1 e^{-\frac{1}{x}}dx > \frac{1}{4}e^{-\frac{4}{3}}$

Some Inequalities

This is not too hard to show. If we let $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$ then one thing we can note is that $e^{-\frac{4}{3}}$ is just $f(\frac{3}{4})$. We also know that $e^{-\frac{4}{3}} = \int_0^1{e^{-\frac{4}{3}}\text{d}x}$. From here, lets divide by $4$. The LHS becomes $\frac{1}{4}e^{-\frac{4}{3}}$, which is what we want. For the RHS, what we can recognize is that $$\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1{e^{-\frac{4}{3}}\text{d}x}=\frac{1}{4}\left(\int_0^{\frac{1}{4}}{e^{-\frac{4}{3}}\text{d}x}+\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{\frac{1}{2}}{e^{-\frac{4}{3}}\text{d}x}+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{3}{4}}{e^{-\frac{4}{3}}\text{d}x}+\int_{\frac{3}{4}}^1{e^{-\frac{4}{3}}\text{d}x}\right)
=\int_{\frac{3}{4}}^1{e^{-\frac{4}{3}}\text{d}x}$$
Recall that we said $f(\frac{3}{4})=e^{-\frac{4}{3}}$, which means the integral then becomes: $$\int_{\frac{3}{4}}^1{f\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\text{d}x}$$
$f(x)$ is a continuously increasing function, so; $$f(x)\ge f\left(\frac{3}{4}\right) \text{for }x\ge\frac{3}{4}$$
It follows that;$$\int_{\frac{3}{4}}^1{f(x)\text{d}x}\ge\int_{\frac{3}{4}}^1{f\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\text{d}x}$$
Therefore;
$$4\int_{\frac{3}{4}}^1{f(x)\text{d}x}=\int_0^1{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}\text{d}x}\gt\frac{1}{4}e^{-\frac{4}{3}}$$
